# aws cloud formation add public key for github

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have my cloud formation script working nicely however I create 4 x micro instances on the cloud formation setup, I want to import the same public key to all 4 instances which are linked to a github account and any other I create after. how would I achieve this ?

Comment: where these key should be created ?  On a file on the instance ?  Where the key can be read / taken from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by this way:

1. Save the public key content in a file and upload to s3 bucket (you can set permission on it).
2. add the script to download the key and save to some where in the `user data` when create new ec2 instance in Cloudformation template.
3. If you create the ec2 instance via `launch configuration and auto scaling`, you need add it to their `user data`.

If the public key didn't change frequently, maybe you can paste the content into `user data` directly.

Comment: would you use the files section of the user data ? I like your method so I will upvote and accept

Comment: Thanks. Yes, in `User data`, you can put all commands in there as bash scripts.